# Injecting controller into another controller during tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I’m using Jasmine to test my Angular application.  Some of the controllers are extended with a separate access controller giving them an initialisation function:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("myCtrl", ["$scope", "someOtherServices", function($scope, someOtherServices) {
  var _this = this;
  $controller('accessController', { accessCtrl: _this });

  // Some more functions

  _this.init(function() {
    // Load in the data
  });

}]);
```

The init function comes from the accessController which uses an Access service, and looks something like this:

```
angular.module("myApp").controller("accessController", ["Access", "accessCtrl", function(Access, accessCtrl) {

  //Some initial setup

  accessCtrl.init = function (func) {

  Access.checkPermissions().then(function() {
    // Permissions specific config
    func();
  });

}]);
```

My test spec looks something like this:

```
describe('myCtrl', function() {

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));

  var $controller;

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_){
    $controller = _$controller_;
  }));

  describe('someTest', function() {
    var $scope, controller, Contacts;

    beforeEach(function() {
      $scope = {};
      someOtherServices = {};

      myCtrl = $controller('myCtrl', {$scope:$scope, someOtherServices: someOtherServices});
    });

    it ('Does something as expected', function() {
      expect(myCtrl.someFunction).toBe(‘pass value’);
    });
  });

});
```

The problem I get is that with the line `$controller('accessController', { accessCtrl: _this });` in the controller, the test fails with the error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: AccessProvider <- Access <- accessController
```

Although I can mock the services that are injected into the controller I’m directly testing, I can’t find a way of mocking the Access service to be injected into the accessController.  How can this be achieved?  The docs say "If you need to test a nested Controller you must create the same scope hierarchy in your test that exists in the DOM:" but if I create this hierarchy in the spec it’s not used in the test.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Access` is mocked as any other service with [`angular.mock.module`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/function/angular.mock.module):

```
beforeEach(module('myApp', {
  Access: { ... }
}));
```

It doesn't matter if it is used in controller or anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks.  What's the difference between injecting the service to the module as in your answer, and injecting it into the controller like all the other services in the question?

Comment: The dependency in $controller affects only instantiated controller (it is called local dependency). This way it is a bit simpler, but it won't work if there's more than just a controller. Both ways can be used for testing.